# upload file to nexus

Tags: linux, jenkins, groovy, nexus

I am trying to upload a file to nexus with jenkinsfile, is there a way to upload a file and overwrite the existing file with newly uploaded so that there will be only 1 file at nexus folder

upload and replace the existing file with new file with nexusArtifactUploader

```
    nexusArtifactUploader(
    nexusVersion: 'nexus3',
    protocol: 'http',
    nexusUrl: 'my.nexus.address',
    groupId: 'com.example',
    version: version,
    repository: 'RepositoryName',
    credentialsId: 'CredentialsId',
    artifacts: [
        [artifactId: projectName,
         classifier: '',
         file: 'my-service-' + version + '.jar',
         type: 'jar']
    ]
 )
```

or is it possible to upload and replace through curl command??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: is there any flag/attribute   am  I missing to replace the existing file with new file??